# Print number of integers in a file after storing them in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, file, io

I have to store all integers in a file into an array then print the array and number of integers in the file.

Here is the method to store integers in the array. It works fine because my output in my second method prints `index = i, element = array[i]` properly.

```
public static Integer [ ] returnFileIntegers(String filename) {
  int i = 0;
  int x = 0;
  Integer [ ] array = new Integer[10000]; //instantiate array of 10000 integers
  if(filename.length() == 0){
     System.out.println("Please enter the file name as the 1st commandline argument.");
  }
  else {   //attempt connect and read file 
     File file = new File(filename);
     Scanner inputFromFile = null;
     try {
        inputFromFile = new Scanner(file);
     } 
     catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.print("ERROR: File not found for \"");
        System.out.println(filename+"\"");
     }        
     //if made connection to file, read file
     if(inputFromFile != null){         
        System.out.print("Reading from file \"" + filename + "\":\n");
        //loop and print to check if file connected

        //read next integer and store into array
        while (inputFromFile.hasNextLine()) {
           try {
              x = inputFromFile.nextInt();
              array[i] = x;
              i++;
              System.out.println(x);

           } 
           catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
              inputFromFile.next();
           }
           catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
           }
        }   
     }
  }
  return array;
}
```

This is the method I made to print the array and number of integers. I know it is wrong because I am printing `array.length` but I do not know what I should use there to make it print the **amount of integers** rather than the **array length**.

```
  public static void printArrayIndexInteger(Integer [ ] array, String filename) {
  //print number of integer in file
  System.out.println("Number of integers in file \"" + filename + "\" = " + array.length);
  //print array index and elements
  for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
     if(array[i] != null){
     System.out.print("\nindex = " + i + ", ");
     System.out.print("element = " + array[i]);
     }
  }
}
```

This is what output currently looks like:

```
Number of integers in file "groceries.csv" = 10000

index = 0, element = 3
index = 1, element = 12
index = 2, element = 1
index = 3, element = 1
index = 4, element = 5
index = 5, element = 1
```

What it should be:

```
Number of integers in file "groceries.csv" = 6

index = 0, element = 3
index = 1, element = 12
index = 2, element = 1
index = 3, element = 1
index = 4, element = 5
index = 5, element = 1
```

How do I get the method to print the amount of elements in the array rather than the array length?

Answer (score 1):

It's saying 10000 because that's how you declared it:

`Integer[] array = new Integer[10000]`

Those extra indices still exist and have the value of `null` by default. The array length *is* equal to the number of elements in the array. If you don't know the size beforehand consider using an `ArrayList` whose size can be adjusted.

The only way to know how many numbers are in your array is to loop through it and count, but an `ArrayList` would be a better solution than assigning your array an arbitrarily large length.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ArrayList instead:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also, replace adding

```
array[i] = x;
i++;
```

With:

```
array.add(x);
```

Auto (un)boxing makes int assignable to Integer.
At the end replace

```
return array;
```

With

```
return array.toArray(new Integer[array.size()]);
```